# Android:Robotium: Tab click with only icon

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have tab layout.That has only icons not text.I tried with clickOnImageButton and ClickOnButton clickOnImage and also pressOnMenuItem(R.drwable.icon)but not worked.How can i do this with solo?
Note: Image View present at the top of the tab.(tab is at bottom)

Comment: mean you are using tab activity and you want to do action like change activity when tab click , is it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tabhosts are evil. Luckily i also have had to automate them and so know the answer.

what you do is you have to get the tab bar view (android.R.id.tabs) and then cast it to a Tabhost or a ViewGroup then you can get each of the tabs via .getChildAt(x) where x is the index of the tabs.

```
ViewGroup tabs = (ViewGroup) solo.getView(android.R.id.tabs);
View viewYouWantToDoStuffWith = tabs.getChildAt(x); //change x to the index you want.
```

In your case you would then want something like:

```
solo.clickOnView(viewYouWantToDoStuffWith);
```

Comment: I used: tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(x);

Answer (score 2):

you can use method `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(resourceId));`
where `resourceId` could be something like `R.id.id_Of_Button`.

Comment: i can't use that as button.Its tab host/tab widget.

Comment: this is my tab layout                                                <TabHost                                                       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >                                                                    i have 3 tabs. how to click 2nd or 3rd tabs?they have to be identified by their icons.

Answer (score 0):

see this link in that they are using image + text. so remove the text made as image that you have to do it.

```
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/
```

this is only for text you can set that with image and made as custom tab.

```
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1
```

Hope it will work for you .

Comment: Hey i don't want tab layout example...I'm asking a test case to do tat in robotium. 'm asking is there any option for click on tab icon in robotium?

Comment: see what's my comment ? you told me that you want to do action on tab activity and now you change your answer . can you describe in more i'm not getting you

Comment: can you please read my question once again?. i thought you are in line with  question.